# How to access other table's attributes using associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

"Hello everyone" I'm practicing a little bit with rails right now and I'm having issues understanding how to access data with associations. Currently I have 3 tables, Doctors, Patients and Appointments.

```
      class CreateDoctors < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :doctors do |t|
          t.string :name

          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
    end

        class CreatePatients < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :patients do |t|
          t.string :name

          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
    end

        class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :appointments do |t|
          t.date :date_appointment
          t.references :doctor, index: true, foreign_key: true
          t.references :patient, index: true, foreign_key: true

          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
    end
```

With this I'm trying to create a form to insert record on Appointments table, this way I can access and get the names for either doctors or patients after submitting the form.

```
    <%= form_for(@appointment) do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :date, "Choose a date for your appointment" %>
 <%= f.collection_select(:doctor_id, Doctor.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The data is being inserted, but when I call the Show "Template" is giving me an error saying that the parameter for doctor in "Nil" even though it has a value.

```
    <%= @appointment.doctor.name %>
```

And here's the appointment controller data

```
        class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController

        def index
        end

        def show

        end

        def new
            @appointment = Appointment.new
        end

        def create
            @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)
            if @appointment.save
                redirect_to @appointment
            else
                render "New"
            end
        end

        private

        def appointment_params
            params.require(:appointment).permit(:date, :doctor_id, :patient_id)
        end

        def find_appointment
            @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
        end



        end
```

What I want to do is basically be able to render or show the names of doctors or patients according to the value of the attributes on the row that is being created after creating a new row with the form.

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :doctor
      belongs_to :patient
    end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :doctors, through: :appointments
end
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you post your models as well?. I'm guessing you missed to mention associations in them.

Comment: Just did! Sorry forgot to add them. Thx for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but aren't you forgetting to set the @appointment var?

```
 def show
   @appointment = Appointment.find(params['id'])
 end
```

(should work if you have a route for this)

Comment: WHAAAAAAAAT?! WHY!?!?!? omg I been into this the whole day. I don't get it isn't supposed to be called if that function is already defined? I defined that below private and I thought that was getting called from there. Thank you so much for your help I feel so dumb right now.